# Error after adding CSS code to my module (ODOO 12)

Tags: css, xml, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

i have a problem with 3 images fields that i want them on the same row , so i Added some css code in my module directory like this : **odoo/addons/GestionIMMO/static/src/scss/GestionIMMO.scss**

this is my GestionIMMO.scss code :

```
.mmligne{text-align:right;}
```

this is my gesimmo_views.xml code

```
<odoo>
     <template id="assets_backend" name="GestionIMMO assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/GestionIMMO/static/src/css/GestionIMMO.css"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_form_gesimmo">
      <field name="name">Product</field>
      <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='default_code']" position="after">
              <group>
                <field name="prop" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="ref" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="surface" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="immo_cat" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="immo_titre" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="immo_date" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <div class="mmligne">
                  <field name="img_one" widget="image" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="img_two" widget="image" style="width:300%%"/>
                  <field name="img_three" widget="image" style="width:300%%"/>
                  </div>
              </group>
          </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='standard_price']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='barcode']" position="attributes" nolabel="true">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='categ_id']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='type']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='default_code']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//label[@for='standard_price']" position="attributes">
     <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='taxes_id']" position="after">
              <group>
                <field name="nbre_ch" style="width:200%%"/>
                  <field name="pr" style="width:200%%"/>
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <field name="rue" placeholder="Rue" style="width:200%%"/>
              <field name="gouv" placeholder="Gouvernorat" style="width:200%%"/>
              <field name="ville" placeholder="Ville" style="width:200%%"/>
              <field name="codepostal" placeholder="Code postal" style="width:200%%"/>
              <field name="pays" placeholder="Pays" style="width:200%%"/>
              </group>
          </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='taxes_id']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//field[@name='list_price']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <label for="name" position="replace">
                    <label for="name"  string="Nom du bien immobilier"/>
                </label>
          <label for="sale_ok" position="replace">
                    <label for="sale_ok"  string="A Vendre"/>
                </label>
          <label for="purchase_ok" position="replace">
                    <label for="purchase_ok"  string="A Louer"/>
                </label>
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='rue']" position="before">
                   <button name="open_map" string="Localisation sur Google Maps" type="object" class="oe_highlight" style="width:100%%"/>
                </xpath>
              <xpath expr="//page[@name='variants']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//page[@name='sales']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//page[@name='purchase']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
           <xpath expr="//page[@name='inventory']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
          <!--<xpath expr="//button[@name='uom_name']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
          </xpath>-->
         <!-- <xpath expr="//page[@name='shop']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>-->

            </field>
    </record>



</odoo>
```

and i had this error :

```
 The style compilation failed, see the error below. Your recent actions may be the cause, please try reverting the changes you made.
Could not get content for /GestionIMMO/static/src/css/GestionIMMO.css defined in bundle 'web.assets_backend'.
```

ps : i inherited the product_template view

**PLEASE HELP**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the **scss** =>  **GestionIMMO/static/src/scss/GestionIMMO.scss**
where on the assets you add the wrong path ref **/GestionIMMO/static/src/css/GestionIMMO.css**.

Correct to the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/GestionIMMO/static/src/scss/GestionIMMO.scss"/>
```

Thanks